# What is more efficient? vector.assign vs vector.erase

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, time-complexity

When a vector exists and tries to erase the back of that vector.
Is it efficient to use an 'vector.assign' in terms of time complexity? Or is it efficient to use 'vector.erase'?

Please let me know the time complexity in each case.

[For example]

```
vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

// 1. use assign
v.assign(v.begin(), v.begin() + 5);

// 2. use erase
v.erase(v.begin() + 5, v.end());
```

Comment: They have two radically different behaviours. `assign` writes over. The assigned elements are still in the vector. `erase` removes. The erased elements are no longer in the vector. Which behavour do you want?

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) it's undefined behavior to call `v.assign(v.begin(), ...);` in the first place because `v.begin()` is an iterator into `v`.

Comment: Good eyes, @NathanPierson . Didn't spot the overwrite.

Comment: just use resize: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: I would like to use vectors that consist only of elements from the beginning section of vectors to a certain index. @user4581301

Comment: Then 

vector<int> v2; 
v2.assign(v.begin(), v.begin() + 5);
v = v2;

and

v.erase(v.begin() + 5, v.end());

Which is more efficient? @NathanPierson

Comment: oh Is resize faster than the two above? @doug

Comment: Test and measure to be sure, but `resize` for a `vector` of `int` should merely be moving the end pointer. With a more complex datatype in the `vector` you would have to also factor in the calling of destructors. Note that it won't even give the excess memory back.

Comment: @user4581301 `erase()` doesn't give excess memory back either. For good reasons. There's a method called `shrink_to_fit()` that's implementation dependent and if it does it's likely to copy the vector and release all the memory in the first.  Bleah.

Comment: For more on what @doug and I are talking about, consult vector's Iterator invalidation rules. Some lovely people have aggregated  the library container invalidation rules and translated them from Language Lawyer to English in the aptly-named [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to use vectors that consist only of elements from the beginning section of vectors to a certain index.

It's most efficient to use `resize`, because that's what that function is for.

For what its worth, self-`assign`ment is not allowed for containers.